# Ubuntu 20.04 in VirtualBox doesn't run

Tags: boot, 20.04, virtualbox

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 in VirtualBox with these specs for months.

[image]

Today when I started the computer, I saw that it was not working and it was stuck at a black screen. First these boot messages appear, and then the screen turns black and nothing happens.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What host OS for the VM? Can you still boot the installation media for Ubuntu 20.04 in VirtualBox on your system?

Comment: Host OS is windows 10. Yes I can still  install new ubuntu machine.

Comment: Can you [boot into recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) ?

Comment: No, I can't go to recovery mode by pressing shift or escape.

Comment: Perhaps the disk is full? Try to enter a console with CTRL+ALT+F2 ...

Comment: I can enter to tty. Now what should I do in the terminal to find out where the problem is? I checked storage size and find that's almost full.

Comment: Well at the very least, what does the [system log](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/viewing-and-monitoring-log-files) show?

Comment: Had similar problem. Host has Ubuntu Server 18.04 and tried to run VM on Ubuntu Server 20.04.6. Gets stuck immediately on kernel. Tried Ubuntu Server 20.04.5. The same problem, but now chance 50/50. Nothing helped. Went back on 18.04 and everything is fine